# Running the EVM in Casper

Tags: gas, miner

- In Casper will miners still be required to power the EVM and execute contracts?
- Will miners still receive rewards from gas but not rewards from transaction verification?
- Will EVM contract execution still use the GPU or will it use the CPU now?

Comment: In my understanding, for each block, there will be a designated miner to execute the contracts and verify all the transactions in that block. By accomplishing the aforementioned tasks, the miner gets rewards. It might not be accurate, but it's the rough idea.